# moment add doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to add a day to moment of Thursday:02:45 which is Friday 02:45 but nothing is getting added.

```
console.log(m.opening[1]); //returns "Thursday 02:45" moment
m.opening[1] = m.opening[1].add(1, 'days');
console.log(m.opening[1]); //returns "Thursday 02:45" moment
m.opening[1] = moment(m.opening[1]).add(1, 'days');
console.log(m.opening[1]); //returns "Thursday 02:45" moment
m.opening[1] = m.opening[1].clone().add(1, 'days');
console.log(m.opening[1]); //returns "Thursday 02:45" moment
```

*not sure if this is useful but i'm using "moment": "^2.13.0" & "moment-range": "^2.2.0",*

Comment: so, `m.opening[1]` is literally, only, and exactly the string `"Thursday 02:45"` ?

Comment: no its an actual moment as in Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "Thursday 02:45" ....

Comment: your first attempt works fine https://jsfiddle.net/9re2gvst/

Comment: can you check https://jsfiddle.net/9sgz85js/1/

Comment: it didn't work until I removed the tz stuff - updated to output `dddd HH:mm a` - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/9sgz85js/2/

Comment: I've added timezone library, will update the question now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9sgz85js/3/

Comment: doesn't matter ... what matters is, you're looking at the console.log output and seeing the value of `_i` property - look at that `_d` property instead ... I don't know what either of them are, you'd have to ask the author if it's that important

Comment: _d is showing Saturday adding one day to Thursday is Friday